# remove weird space between body and footer html

Tags: html, css, header, margin, footer

I'm new to HTML5 and CSS3, even more on flexbox. Please help me remove this unwanted space between body and footer.

I've looked around here in stackoverflow and google but nothing worked. They all suggested checking my margins, and I did check all of them but to no avail. Tried adjusting margin, padding, and border for most of the divs but still I can't find the culprit.

> Chrome:
>   [image]
>
> index.html

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="header flex-container">
            <li class="nav flex-item">About</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Links</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="content flex-container">
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="main flex-item">
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
    </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
<footer>footer here</footer>
```

> style.css

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.flex-container{
    /* flexbox properties*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item{
    /*flexbox properties*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

ul{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav{
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
}

.content{
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar{
    background-color: grey;
    flex: 1;
}    

.main{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex: 2;
}

footer{
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

> Edit: This is what I get in Firefox. Also, moved the footer inside body tag, as suggested in one of the comments.
>   [image]
>
> Edit 2: I copied my code to Codepen and saw these weird characters. When I deleted them, it solved my problem. But looking at my editor (I tried Sublime and Notepad++ already), there's no special characters!!! This is driving me crazy.
>   [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, there's no space for me. https://jsfiddle.net/461gac7L/ . Does this happen on a specific browser?

Comment: `footer` should be inside `body` tag

Comment: @SuperUser tried, didn't work

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru I have no idea why. I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Unwanted space between body and footer because in div end some dotted character is visible i.e (.............)

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.flex-container{
    /* flexbox properties*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item{
    /*flexbox properties*/
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

ul{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav{
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
}

.content{
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar{
    background-color: grey;
    flex: 1;
}    

.main{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex: 2;
}

footer{
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="header flex-container">
            <li class="nav flex-item">About</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Links</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="content flex-container">
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="main flex-item">
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>footer here</footer>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks this worked perfectly! Although, can you point me to which part you changed? I can't find it.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I realized you didn't change anything in the code. Do you know why there were unwanted characters? This is the first time it happened and I've been using SublimeText with different languages.

Comment: @reiallenramos  I have removed doted character that is visible in snippet code. By mistake you have typed extra character and this is not visible in sublime because you have not installed plugin. for this pls follow this link  https://github.com/TuureKaunisto/highlight-dodgy-chars

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue with your html
[Look into this screenshot problem is with you html try using footer inside your body tag](http://chrome-extension://nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj/edit.html)

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LSKhan/r0u3h8rL/)

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="header flex-container">
            <li class="nav flex-item">About</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Links</li>
            <li class="nav flex-item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="content flex-container">
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="main flex-item">
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        This is the content<br />
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar flex-item">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer here</footer>
</body>
```